# C-Tab cannot be recognized in terminal?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I want to bind company-mode-map to C-tab, but it seems doesn't work. And I typed C-h k C-tab, it just said that I typed TAB but not C-Tab. It works in Xwindows, is there any way to fix the problem in terminal mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [these directions](http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2009/01/10/how-to-use-ctrl-tab-in-gnu-screen/), which are targeted at using GNU screen, but they work for me in regular terminal mode.  After adding:

```
*vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl ~Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;5;9~") \n \
    Ctrl Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;6;9~") \n
```

to my .Xresources file, `C-tab` is recognized in my terminal, and the binding found by Emacs.